# How can I remove field focus with a delay using pure jQuery?

Tags: jquery, focus, delay, settimeout, blur

Please consider the following code:

```
  //Focus on the field on page load.
  $("#user_login").focus();

  //Remove prompt after a couple of seconds.
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $("#user_login").blur();},
  3000);
```

I have several tooltips and other events tied to #user_login input on focus. But not to annoy user, I want to remove focus after a couple of seconds.

This is a way I'm doing right now - as I can understand delay() won't work in this instance. Is there any other pure jquery way to do this?  Something along the lines of:

```
$("#user_login").focus().delay(3000).blur();
```

Thanks

P.S.:
My solution works fine right now as it is, this more for educational purposes.

Comment: try passing an argument to `blur` and see if its added to internal jquery queue `$("#user_login").focus().delay(3000).blur(0);`

Comment: Seems to me like `$("#user_login").focus().delay(3000).blur();` should work fine.  It's not?

Comment: Nope - delay is for animations only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`delay()` only works with animations.

Make a plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.promptTooltip = function(duration) {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.focus();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $this.blur();
        }, duration);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Use the plugin:

```
$('#testme').promptTooltip(3000);
```

Here's a silly demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/gKECa/

Comment: I figured that - I mentioned that in my question. This is just an example of want I want - delay obviously won't work. But since I don't know the correct method name, I put this as an example of what I'm trying to achieve.